# Applying watermark on an image

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I'm trying to apply watermark on an image using the following imagemagick command

```
convert input.png watermark.png.png -gravity northwest -composite output.png
```

The input png file size is 16KB and the watermark file size is 900bytes, but when I executed the above command to apply a watermark, the output png size is 61KB which is almost 4X the size of the original input png file. Is there any better way of applying a watermark to an image file with much better result in terms of output filesize

Test Image: https://res.cloudinary.com/deks86ilr/image/upload/v1533015495/1_rnpbye.png

Test watermark: https://res.cloudinary.com/deks86ilr/image/upload/v1533015494/2_usmonh.png

Comment: Try saving as 8-bit total color as PNG8. `convert input.png watermark.png.png -gravity northwest -composite -depth 8 PNG8:output.png`, if your output does not have transparency. Post links to your two input images so we can test separately, if that does not help.

Comment: @fmw42 I have updated the original question with links to the two input images. I have tried your code snippet, the output size has reduced drastically, however, the quality of the output image also went down

Comment: You can use other tools to optimize png images, for example, pngcrush. See https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#png_non-im

Comment: I note that your original input is type palette. That means that it is PNG8 with only 8-bits of color per pixel. Your output is PNG24 or 24-bits of color per pixel. That accounts for the file size increase. My use of PNG8: for the output makes the output the same palette type as the input. You can try other quality values to improve the result. See https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality. When I process with my PNG8: output command, I see no visible obvious quality difference. So perhaps it is your version of ImageMagick or libpng. You do not say what you used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my results of processing of your images with my PNG8 output using ImageMagick 6.9.10.8 Q16 with libpng 1.6.34.

I note that your input image was type palette, which means it is 8-bits of color per pixel and not 24-bit color. So it is already a low quality image.

Input (~16 KB):

[image]

Watermark Image (white on transparency -- so it is invisible here):

[image]

Convert to 24-bit PNG:

```
convert input.png watermark.png -gravity northwest -compose over -composite input_with_watermark.png
```

[image]

I see no significant visible quality loss but the output is now increase from 16 KB to 60 KB. But you can use tools such as pngcrush to compress it further.

Convert to 8-bit PNG:

```
convert input.png watermark.png -gravity northwest -compose over -composite PNG8:input_with_watermark2.png
```

[image]

The file size is now back to about 16 KB. But as you note the quality is a little poorer. This is likely because the input image (at 8-bits and has 217 colors) was first read back to 24-bits, then watermarked, which included new shades of white and then quantized back to 8-bits, but contains only 84 colors colors.

Another way is to add +dither -colors 256 to the command (the +dither turns off dithering):

```
convert 1_rnpbye.png 2_usmonh.png -gravity northwest -compose over -composite +dither -colors 256 PNG8:watermark3.png
```

[image]

This is a bit better, since it now uses 189 colors and still has a file size of 16 KB.

One final method is to save the colors from your input to a colortable image. Then use -remap to recolor the output using that colortable:

```
convert 1_rnpbye.png -unique-colors colortable.gif
convert 1_rnpbye.png 2_usmonh.png -gravity northwest -compose over -composite +dither -remap colortable.gif PNG8:watermark4.png
```

[image]

This results in 8-bit output with 227 colors and still a file size of about 16 KB. So it has a few more colors than your input and visually looks about the same quality as your input.

If you cannot reproduce these results, then perhaps you should upgrade either or both ImageMagick and libpng.

Comment: I have edited my post above, since I had originally posted a 24-bit result for the 8-bit example code. I have fixed that and added another better method to get to 8-bit results, which preserves more of the original number of 8-bit colors.

Comment: Nice touch with using the palette of the original image, but why does that result in more colours? I would have thought that by using a palette you'd limit the colours to those available in that palette?

Comment: I do not know. It puzzled me also. Perhaps because the colorable image's color map has 256 colors. 226 are the actually colors and the rest of the color map is filled with black. I do not understand this. But that is a guess.